# SKCameraNode.position didSet does not get fired when moved with an SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skaction, skcameranode

I have a simple subclass of `SKCameraNode` that I called `InteractiveCameraNode`.  For now it's very simple: I need things to happen when my camera's position changes.  Here is what I did:

```
class InteractiveCameraNode: SKCameraNode {
   // MARK: - Properties
   var enableInteraction = true
   var positionResponders = [(CGPoint, CGPoint) -> Void]()


   /// Calls every closure in the `positionResponders` array
   override var position: CGPoint {
      didSet {
         if enableInteraction {
            for responder in positionResponders {
               responder(oldValue, position)
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Since I might have multiple things happening when the camera moves, I have an array of closures that are called when the camera's position is changed.  So far everything works perfectly except the `didSet` observer does not get called if I move the camera using an action.  If I use a constraint on the camera to make it track a node and then move that node with an action, it works.  If I move the camera by hand, it works.  Why won't it work with actions?

Answer (score 1):

my previous answer was incorrect 100%.. Whatever lead me to that answer was some other mistake on my part and I apologize.. I learned something useful today as well :)

It looks like that behavior you're seeing is either A) a bug or B) some deeper mechanism of Swift / SK that I don't understand.

Here is a workaround that worked for me in playground:

```
class Noder: SKSpriteNode {

  var myPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero { didSet { print(position) } }

  func initialize(scene: SKScene) {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scene.addChild(self)
  }

  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    position = touches.first!.location(in: self.scene!)
  }

  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print(self.position)
    run(.moveBy(x: -35, y: 0, duration: 0.5), completion: {
      self.myPosition = self.position
    })
  }
}
```

to use:

```
// In didmovetoview:
let node = Noder(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
node.initialize(scene: self)
```

output, showing that the actual position has been updated from an action and `didSet`:

> (50.0, -118.0)
>   (14.9999971389771, -118.0)

---

But this will probably be too slow for what you want, so you will be better off manually setting `position` or `myPosition` in `update()` every frame (whichever one will work for `didSet` lol..)

(Credit to Confused for this paragraph).

---

Also, I wonder if a KVO would work here.. I haven't used them, but CameraNode is already an NSObject... something to look into maybe since this is likely a bug of some sort...

Comment: Dorry for not knowing but...  what is a KVO?

Comment: @BadgerBadger https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA

Comment: i generally dislike the whole delegate / kvo / messenger / signal patterns (i like doing things manually, top to bottom), but in this case I would explore this option since it's sounds like exactly what you are trying to do @BadgerBadger

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

Running an action that mutates the position of the calling `Node` subclass doesn't set its position, the property observer (in your case the `didSet`) isn't invoked and thus, your code is never executed.

> In this case, the solution is to use `SKSceneDelegate` and compare the
>   node's position across two of its callbacks. You save the node's
>   initial position in update(_:for:), which is called at the beginning
>   of each frame, then calculate any change in position in
>   `didEvaluateActions(for:)`, which is called after actions have been
>   evaluated.

[Read more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/detecting_changes_at_each_step_of_an_animation)